# Drag and Drop event no longer firing

Tags: c#, winforms, drag-and-drop, vsto, outlook-addin

I was having issues with my project with drag and drop no longer working.
I created a new simple project to isolate the issue. (based on [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/vsto/walkthrough-displaying-custom-task-panes-with-e-mail-messages-in-outlook?view=vs-2017))
I simply created a listview (listView1), changed the background to blue.  I then added 3 events from the TaskPaneControl designer which I then added a line of code as follows:

```
private void listView1_DragDrop(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string test = "";
}

private void listView1_DragEnter(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string test = "";
}

private void listView1_DragOver(object sender, DragEventArgs e)
{
    string test = "";
}
```

I put a breakpoint in each line and expected it to be hit.  The breakpoint will hit TaskPane_VisibleChanged but for some reason it won't hit the listview1_DragXXX

Comment: Are you running the program as Administrator? Drag Drop doesn't work for apps running as admin

Comment: I believe I am running as Admin.  I think the issue might be that allowdrop is set to false - I will confirm tomorrow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a change to the designer and in doing so I inadvertently set allowdrop on the user control be set to false.  Once I set it to true it worked.